Why can't I perform a Dunnet's test directly?
I have read that the Dunnett's test is basically a post-hoc test that should be performed after a ANOVA (statistically significant).
Here, I show that ANOVA is not effective in my context because the significant differences in means are occurring between groups that are not the control group.
Running this simple code:
rm(list=ls())
# Load the packages
if (!require(DescTools)) install.packages('DescTools')
if (!require(ggplot2)) install.packages('ggplot2')

# Create a sample dataset
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  treatment = rep(c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", "Treatment3"), each = 20),
  response = c(rnorm(20, mean = 5, sd = 1),
               rnorm(20, mean = 5.1, sd = 1),
               rnorm(20, mean = 5.4, sd = 1),
               rnorm(20, mean = 4.4, sd = 1))
)

boxplot(data$response ~data$treatment)


# Perform an ANOVA
anova_model <- aov(response ~ treatment, data = data)
summary(anova_model)

gives:
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
treatment    3  11.15   3.715   4.433 0.00632 **
Residuals   76  63.69   0.838                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

This tells me that there are statistically significant differences among the group means in my data (looking at the plot, I would say between means of Treatment2 and Treatment3).
# Perform the Dunnett test
DunnettTest(x=data$response, g=data$treatment)

gives:
  Dunnett's test for comparing several treatments with a control :  
    95% family-wise confidence level

$Control
                          diff     lwr.ci      upr.ci   pval    
Treatment1-Control -0.09699539 -0.7908913 0.596900528 0.9750    
Treatment2-Control  0.34827290 -0.3456230 1.042168819 0.4880    
Treatment3-Control -0.68878697 -1.3826829 0.005108952 0.0522 .  

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

which tells me that none of the Treatment has a mean that is different than the control. So here ANOVA does not help at all and so I am wondering why it should be performed first.

See this page for discussion about why preliminary ANOVA isn't generally required.

Thanks. Here, however, Dunnett's test does not contradict ANOVA

Have edited : Here, I show that ANOVA is not effective in my context because the significant differences in means are occurring between groups that are not the control group.

If you didn't mean to test that hypothesis, why would you use the ANOVA then?

@Laut567: ANOVA asks a different question than Dunnett's. I am not sure what you mean by ANOVA not being "effective"... So I am not sure how your question differs than https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/do-we-need-a-global-test-before-post-hoc-tests

Because Dunnet’s test is a post hoc test (at least what I read).

The term "post-hoc" seems not to be well defined, as this page discusses
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63665/meaning-of-post-hoc-multiple-comparisons
But it is clear that Dunnett's test (and almost all followup multiple comparisons tests) can be run on their own and their interpretation does not depend on overall ANOVA giving p<0.05.
